# Make a SVG image with vector stroke and drop-shadow

Tags: svg, svg-filters, dropshadow

I'm trying to get drop-shadow of svg image.

I noticed that the stroke gets also blurred (I mean the vector lines are pixelized)... when I apply drop-shadow filter. Isn't it possible to keep the stroke line sharp and add drop shadow behind it??

[the svg image looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o69t.png)

[the second question..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HTWh.png)

```html
<filter  color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" height="200%" id="drop-shadow" width="200%" x="-50%" y="-50%">
 <!--  Take source alpha, offset it by angle/distance and blur it by size  -->
 <feOffset  dx="5.87" dy="3.81" id="offset" in="SourceAlpha" result="SA-offset"></feOffset>
 <feGaussianBlur  id="blur" in="SA-offset" result="SA-o-blur" stdDeviation="1.75"></feGaussianBlur>
 <!--  Apply a contour by using a color curve transform on the alpha and clipping the result to the input  -->
 <feComponentTransfer  in="SA-o-blur" result="SA-o-b-contIN">
  <feFuncA  id="contour" tableValues="0 1" type="table"></feFuncA>
 </feComponentTransfer>
 <feComposite  in="SA-o-blur" in2="SA-o-b-contIN" operator="in" result="SA-o-b-cont"></feComposite>
 <!--  Adjust the spread by multiplying alpha by a constant factor  -->
 <feComponentTransfer  in="SA-o-b-cont" result="SA-o-b-c-sprd">
  <feFuncA  id="spread-ctrl" slope="1.1" type="linear"></feFuncA>
 </feComponentTransfer>
 <!--  Adjust color and opacity by adding fixed offsets and an opacity multiplier  -->
 
  <feColorMatrix  id="recolor" in="SA-o-b-c-sprd" result="SA-o-b-c-s-recolor" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0.6 0">
  </feColorMatrix>
 
  <!--  Generate a reasonably grainy noise input with baseFrequency between approx .5 to 2.0. And add the noise with k1 and k2 multipliers that sum to 1  -->
 <feTurbulence  baseFrequency="1.98" numOctaves="6" result="fNoise" stitchTiles="noStitch" type="fractalNoise"></feTurbulence>
 <feColorMatrix  in="fNoise" result="clipNoise" type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 7 -3"></feColorMatrix>
 
  <feComposite  id="noisemix" in="SA-o-b-c-s-recolor" in2="clipNoise" k1="0" k2="1" operator="arithmetic" result="SA-o-b-c-s-r-mix">
  </feComposite>
 <!--  Merge the shadow with the original  -->
 <feMerge>
  <feMergeNode  in="SA-o-b-c-s-r-mix"></feMergeNode>
  <feMergeNode  in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
 </feMerge>
</filter>
```

Comment: Please post a minimal example with complete source code so we can see what might be causing the blurring.

Comment: I couldn't add the SVG image itself in snippet, because there are too many lines of codes in there... But I added the filter I used, which caused the problem I mentioned above.

Comment: This renders perfectly on a minimal test case (a rect) - so it's really got to be something that your source graphic is triggering.